# Dependency Management for openui5/ sapui5

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, dependency-management, sapui5

Currently I am using github submodules to manage the dependencies of my projects. E.g. Components with subcomponents or component with control libraries or just load the proper openui5 version into my project. Its a working solution, but not best practice alike. Is there a dependency management solution that works with JS and with github repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Officially SAP supports dependency management for OpenUI5 only through Bower. You can find out more information in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coWoQp50dLg

There is also unofficial loader for webpack (https://github.com/MagicCube/ui5-loader), but it seems like project has been abandoned.

SAP Way for developing SAPUI5 applications is using their WebIDE which resolve all framework dependencies for you automatically.

Comment: I am going to setup a bower registry for our components and see if it works better than submodules. Another try could be to use grunt or gulp and just checkout the different git repositories. I will post updates here about my progress.